# Remove duplicate year rows by groups

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` of the following form:-

```
data <- data.table(group = rep(1:3, each = 4), 
    year = c(2011:2014, rep(2011:2012, each = 2),
             2012, 2012, 2013, 2014), value = 1:12)
```

This is only an abstract of my data.

So group `2` has 2 values for `2011` and `2012`. And group 3 has `2` values for the year `2012`. I want to just keep the first row for all the duplicated years.

So, in effect, my `data.table` will become the following:-

```
data <- data.table(group = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 3)),
                   year = c(2011:2014, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2014),
                   value = c(1:5, 7, 9, 11, 12))
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `data.table` option with `duplicated`

```
> data[!duplicated(cbind(group, year))]
   group year value
1:     1 2011     1
2:     1 2012     2
3:     1 2013     3
4:     1 2014     4
5:     2 2011     5
6:     2 2012     7
7:     3 2012     9
8:     3 2013    11
9:     3 2014    12
```

Comment: Also note the `by` argument in `duplicated.data.table`. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

For `data.table`s you can pass `by` argument to `unique` -

```
library(data.table)

unique(data, by = c('group', 'year'))

#   group year value
#1:     1 2011     1
#2:     1 2012     2
#3:     1 2013     3
#4:     1 2014     4
#5:     2 2011     5
#6:     2 2012     7
#7:     3 2012     9
#8:     3 2013    11
#9:     3 2014    12
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use `distinct` from `dplyr` like so:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  distinct(group, year, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
   group year value
1:     1 2011     1
2:     1 2012     2
3:     1 2013     3
4:     1 2014     4
5:     2 2011     5
6:     2 2012     7
7:     3 2012     9
8:     3 2013    11
9:     3 2014    12
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
subset(data, !duplicated(cbind(group, year)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  group_by(group, year) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(group, year))
```